# Variant of Lp spaces

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on the measure space $(\mathbb{R}^d,\Sigma)$, $K\subset \mathbb{R}$ be compact of positive $\mu$-measure, and defined $\frac{d \nu}{d\mu}\triangleq 1_K$ as well as the modified $L^p$ space
$$
\mathbb{L}^p_{\nu}(\Sigma)\triangleq \left\{
f \in L_{\mu,loc}^p(\Sigma): \, \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f|^p d\nu <\infty
\right\} \subseteq L^p_{\nu}(\Sigma).
$$

It is easy to see that in general, the inclusion is strict.

Besides the above inclusion, how are the spaces $\mathbb{L}^p_{\nu}(\Sigma)$ and $L^p_{\nu}(\Sigma)$ related?  Is the former dense in the latter?  If not, is it a Banach space?

*My intuition: $\mathbb{L}_{\nu}^p(\Sigma)$ is a dense subspace of $L_{\nu}^p(\Sigma)$ and it is a locally-convex (TVS) but not Banach.*

Comment: To avoid trivialities you have to assume that $K$ has positive measure under $\mu$.

Comment: Indeed, this makes sense; I made the modification.

Comment: I don 't know if I am missing something but I think the inclusion is not even strict. If $f$ is in RHS and $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x \in K$ and $0$ for $x \notin K$ then $g$ belongs to LHS and $f=g$ a.e. $[\nu]$. So the two spaces are identical.

Comment: Not sure: because if $K_1\subset K_2$ (both satisfying the assumptions) and $\nu_i$ defined accordingly, then $\mathbb{L}_{\nu_1}^p(\Sigma)\subseteq \mathbb{L}_{\nu_2}^p(\Sigma)$ but $L_{\nu_1}^p(\Sigma)\not \subseteq L_{\nu_1}^p(\Sigma)$; so there must be something subtle hapening..

Comment: @AIM_BLB You are probably varying $K$. But $K$ is fixed compact set in this question. .